# Mapping derivative information in uniform to non-uniform grid

Tags: finite-difference, grid

I'm having two sets of grids. One is uniform and another one is not uniform. I will calculate the derivative in uniform grid points and I like to transfer(map)  the derivative to the non-uniform grid points. I have the relationship between uniform and non-uniform grid points.

[A similar question was already asked.](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24780/derivatives-approximation-on-non-uniform-grid) I'd like to get one answer with an example. For the time sake, I consider the following simple example.

The relation between my uniform and the non-uniform grid is
$$x= \zeta^2$$ Let $y(x)$ be the function for which I'd like to calculate the derivative on the non-uniform grid and $y = x^2$. So, $\frac{dy}{dx} =2x$

The uniform grid and derivative information are given, as follows:

[image: uniform grid and derivative]

The non-uniform grid: [image: figure].

I want to find the derivative information in the non-uniform grid by mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Use the chain rule to get the derivative on the non-uniform grid, $\frac{dy}{d\zeta}$:

$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{d\zeta} &= \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{d\zeta}\\
&= \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot 2 \zeta \\
&= \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot 2 \sqrt{x} \\
\end{align}
$$

So if you have a way of computing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ on the uniform grid, you can simply scale it by $2\sqrt{x}$ to get the corresponding $\frac{dy}{d\zeta}$ derivative.

Comment: I think I didn't ask this much easy question! I want to a map function such that, that is a straight line in the second graph.  Please note that the function you provided can't be a straight line!

Comment: In that case, it's not quite clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking for some function $f(x)$ which gives a straight line when plotted against $\xi$? If so, what is the straight line you want? Tell us more about the quantities you already have, and what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: It is quite common in computation, we solve our partial differential equations in a uniform grid (computational plane) and transform that to a non-uniform grid (physical plane). I want to know whether any existing approaches available to transform the derivative from one plane to another.

Comment: In the non-uniform plane, only grids are clustered at some point but domain remains same. I'm looking for a map that makes the one-to-one relation between uniform to non-uniform grids. Sorry for confusing that with Jacobian transformation. In CFD books, use Jacobian transformation to transfer variable. I would like to know, whether the derivative is transformable?

Comment: The method I have shown is exactly how you transfer the derivative from the uniform computational grid to the non-uniform physical grid. The Jacobian of the mapping function $x(\xi)$ definitely shows up. This is essentially the same approach that's shown in the [other answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24780/derivatives-approximation-on-non-uniform-grid), I just substituted your particular $x(\xi)$ relationship. You can read more on this in Section 4.3 of [these notes](https://www.nada.kth.se/kurser/kth/2D1263/l6.pdf). Eq. 4.3 is consistent with what I have given.

Comment: I have learnt those things but I'm unable to relate them geometrically. According to textbooks, I'm looking for $\frac{df}{d \zeta}$ but I don't know whether that will work or not? I tried to make a plot that is not working!